# ¿Cómo cambiar destino de un proyecto a una versión diferente de .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, poo

¿A que se debe el no poder hacer referencia a este como proyecto como destino?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probablemente porque el framework de destino de tu proyecto no coincide.Según veo, tu aplicación es netstandard, y la que intentas enlazar es .net.

Comment: Gracias me fije que las bibliotecas de clases no correspondian a .net sino que a netstandard